# Beautifulsoup use of find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've inherited a function from another developer that is supposed to check whether a body parameter of an email message is an HTML body or plaintext. If it is HTML it attaches a plain and an html version of the body to the message, and if the body is not html it only attaches a plain body.

```
def insertBody(self, body):
    if bool(BeautifulSoup(body, "html.parser").find()):
        b = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        b.attach( MIMEText(html2text.html2text(body),'plain') )
        b.attach( MIMEText(body,'html') )
    else:
        b = MIMEText(body,'text')
    self._msg.attach(b)
    return
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to detect when only a plain body is passed, it only works when I submit a body with `<html>` and `<body>` tags. I'm thinking it could be the use of the `find()` function, but I'm not familiar enough with Beautifulsoup to be able to tell. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Do you want to find a specific tag in html code ?

Comment: @Arpit no, I think it's trying to determine whether the input is html by seeing if it contains any html tags

Comment: There never is a need to call `bool()` when using `if`. `if` **already does this itself**.

Comment: First import beautifulsoup then put this condition if bs4.find('tag_name'):

Comment: @Arpit: no, the code is trying to detect that there is *any HTML-like syntax* in the text. `soup.find()` without arguments returns the  first tag in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test has three problems:

- You don't need to use `bool()` in an `if` test, because the `if` statement already does the exact same thing.
- The test is way too simplistic. As soon as the text has a `<` character in it, followed by text and then *at any point later on* by a `>` character, the test will pass:

  ```
  >>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  >>> BeautifulSoup('<foo bar\n baz> spam ham', 'html.parser').find()
  <foo bar="" baz=""> spam ham</foo>
  ```
- Using `BeautifulSoup` to do a full parse is overkill, the same test can be performed much more efficiently with:

  ```
  import re

  if re.search('<[^>]+>', body):
      # ...
  ```

A regular expression could be tuned to look for HTML tags that are actually valid, like:

```
html = re.compile('<(?:html|head|body)[^>]*>', flags=re.I)
if html.search(body):
```

The above detects opening `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags; adjust as needed to how precise you need this detection to be (there is always a trade-off between precision and false-positives).

Comment: Great. I deduced from the code I saw that BeautifulSoup would only match valid HTML tags but I guess that's not the case